# Where to get the org.apache.* type of libraries and how to configure them?

Tags: java, import, classpath

My Java code uses log4j eg. it tries to:

```
import org.apache.log4j.logger, 
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, 
import org.testng.Assert
```

and many more.
Is there any common place where I can get them? 
Also, how does one configure them?
I downloaded the log4j from apache site but could not configure it properly.
Any help will be appreciated!

Regards,
Multicoder

Comment: What is your main problem? It's not compiling, it fails when run, or your IDE highlights it in red?

Answer (score 1):

you will kick yourself in a second as the answer is in the question!

To get more information about the **org.apache.commons** library you need to go to:

http://commons.apache.org/

-- UPDATE --

Re-reading your question I think you were actually asking about **org.testng** which you can find at:

http://testng.org

Answer (score 0):

add log4j.jar in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

this is where i put the extracted files 
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-log4j-1.2.15
i.e. inside the java's installtion and gave the classpath as 
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-log4j-1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar
in the existing classpath along with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\lib; 
so I made the classpath as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-log4j-1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar;
like this also.
Also tried creating the CLASSPATH as a seperate environment variable(i noted its in a capital letter!) and giving the 
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-log4j-1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar;
value to it.
But neither of the approaches worked so far...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Maven to automatically download them, you can get them manually from
[Maven repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).
This is a trusted source of jars besides the original project site.